# @providesModule naming collision error

Tags: ios, react-native

Node: 4.8.3
NPM: 4.5.0
RN CLI: 1.0.0
RN: 0.34.0
Ignite: 1.13.0

The iOS react-native project I'm working on is actually from another machine Mac machine. I transferred it over my Windows machine and run it in a virtual machine with El Capitan OS. But now I can't even build it. I don't understand what the errors below are. And I'm not really familiar with XCode and OSX.

The error is saying something about naming collisions. I already tried deleting the collisioned files but another file happens to occur. Then delete that file again and then same thing happens. It goes on and on. Already tried deleting the `node_modules` folder then running `npm install` again. I tried running `npm dedupe` and also tried creating a new project using `ignite new MyApp` but it seems to happen.

What did I miss here?

Error Screenshot 1:

[image: Error Screenshot 1]

Error Screenshot 2:

[image: Error Screenshot 2]

Comment: I've removed your request to offer "the whole running project", since that sort of thing is widely interpreted as "fix it for me". We are a bit different on Stack Overflow in that we try not to do that - mainly because we get hundreds of requests for free work every day.  It is also not helpful in the long term, since if you successfully get people to do your work for you, it will encourage your employer not to replace the iOS developer who has left.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem of your react-native-router-flux version. (v3.38.1)

I suspect after transferring it over to the other machine you did `npm install` and got a newer version.

See: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1809

The workaround would be to set a fix version in your package.json.

```
    "react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0",
```

Comment: its already 3.38.0. i can give you the entire project including the xcode project created on the previous machine to see if it even builds on your side. really frustrated on this one already :(

Comment: @MykelAballe: offering to send someone a bunch of files, including executable binaries, is not a good idea. Do you think they would be well advised to run them on their own machine, from a security perspective? What are the risks to doing that, would you say?

Comment: yea i get your point. thanks for the warning but desperate times calls for desperate decisions :(